# different essential ideals

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Does there exist a $C^*$ algebra which has more than one essential ideal?If there exists such a $C^*$ algebra ,suppose $I,J$ are two different essential ideals,$I\subset J$,can we compare the multiplier algebras $M(I)$ and $M(J)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=C[0,1]$. For each $x\in[0,1]$, 
$$
I_x=\{f:\ f(x)=0\}
$$
is an essential ideal. So you have uncountably many of them. And there are more, because finite intersections of essential ideals are again essential.

For the inclusion, one could have $M(I)\subset M(J)$ if $I\subset J$ if $I$ has an approximate unit for $J$; this doesn't require them to be ideals nor essential. I'm not sure what can be said in general. 
.

Comment: But in Olsen's book,there is an exercise:$M(B)\subset M(A)$ when B is a $C^*$ subalgebra of $A$ which contains an approximate unit for A.

Comment: Yes, you need both to be non-degenerate; that could be achieved when $B$ has an approximate unit for $A$.

Comment: Should it be $I\subset J$,we have $M(I)\subset M(J)$?

Comment: I am a little confused.when $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$ which contains an a.u for A,then $M(B)\subset M(A)$.when it comes to ideals,$I\subset J$,$M(J)\subset M(I)$.

Comment: You are right, I need to address that. Hopefully later today.